# Is a stateless app compatible with formlogin?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm struggling for some days with this problem : I have an authentication server with spring security. I use JWT tokens, and as I need my users to be able to logout from the font side, I need not to have a JSESSIONID, so I set the sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

Also I need a login form on the authentication server side, which I manage with formLogin().

Unfortunately, if I use those 2 configs at the same time, once the user have submited the login form, he's not redirected back to the front app.

If I drop the SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS and set the formLogin() part, then the redirection is working, but then I got a session, and logout doesn't work.

If I set SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS and httpBasic(), then the redirection is working, but of course I don't have the login form.

Is there any way to achieve that?

here the config :

```
http.cors().and().csrf().disable().
        authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/token/*").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
//        .formLogin()
//        .loginPage("/login")
//        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

Comment: If you use a login page (form), you doesn't want to login with every request. So you need to save the authentication. Form login saves your authentication in HTTP session.